# Reduce time complexity for double for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity

I am a student and need help in reducing time complexity of my below code. I have python dataframe df which contain customer id as customerid and their purchase date as createdon, in order to find the premium customer ,want to count max purchase for each customer in last 48 hr so created a 48 hr back threshold date as last_48 and ranked the buy date in asc order as buy_rank for each customer id. For this i have written the below code but it takes forever to run for 540k customerid. Please help to optimize my piece of code

```
%%time
c=[]
for i in range(len(df)):
    k=0
    print(i)
    b=df[df['customerid']==df['customerid'].iloc[i]]
    for j in range(len(b)):
        if (df['last_48'].iloc[i] `<b['createdon'].iloc[j]) & (df['buy_rank'].iloc[i]>b['buy_rank'].iloc[j]):`
                k=k+1   
    c.append(k)

df['buy_count']=c


       |customerid |createdon|buy_rank|buy_count|last_48  |
       |-----------|---------|--------|---------|---------|
       |11         |3jan 1:30| 1      | 0       |1jan 1:30|
       |11         |3jan 3:30| 2      | 1       |1jan 3:30|
       |11         |6jan 1:30| 3      | 0       |4jan 1:30|
       |11         |6jan 2:30| 4      | 1       |4jan 2:30|
       |11         |6jan 3:30| 5      | 2       |4jan 3:30|
       |11         |6jan 4:40| 6      | 3       |4jan 4:40|
       |11         |9jan 5:30| 7      | 0       |7jan 5:30|
```

Comment: Any pandas code that has a loop over its rows is almost surely inefficient. Please add a fragment of your data and the expected output to get better advice. Also, the fragment `else: k` is useless and can be removed at once.

Comment: If you're working with dataframe, simple answer. Do not use loops at all. Please provide a sample of the data and a matching sample of the expected output.

Comment: Step 1: The `df['customerid'].iloc[i]==b['customerid'].iloc[j]` condition is always true, so remove it.  Step 2: learn about `df.groupby('customerid')` to treat each customerid as a subset of the data.